# pygame sprite movement mechanics

Tags: pygame, sprite

I have a problem with the mechanics of a platformer game I’m trying to create in pygame. I’m a beginner trying to learn python so this is basically code that I have used from tutorials online and snippets of information found on here.
Can anyone help?

The problem is when the player sprite moves left (by pressing left arrow key) it doesn’t come to a steady stop like when moving in the right direction.
I can’t find what is causing the error.

Code:

```
import pygame as pg

GAME_TITLE = "Plat Game" 
SCREEN_WIDTH = 400 
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 400 
FPS = 60 
GAME_WINDOW = pg.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
GAME_TIMER = 0 
RUNNING_GAME = True 
PLAYER_SIZE_X = 20 
PLAYER_SIZE_Y = 20 
PLAYER_FRICTION = -0.1 
PLAYER_GRAVITY = 0.8 
PLAYER_SPEED = 0.5
PLAYER_VELOCITY_X = 0.0 
PLAYER_VELOCITY_Y = PLAYER_GRAVITY 
PLAT_SIZE_X = 4 
PLAT_SIZE_Y = 4 
player_move_left_key = pg.K_LEFT 
player_move_right_key = pg.K_RIGHT 
WHITE = (255, 255, 255) 
BLACK = (0, 0, 0) 
RED = (255, 0, 0) 
GREEN = (0, 255, 0) 
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
BACK_GROUND_COLOUR = BLACK 
PLAYER_COLOUR = RED

class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      self.image = pg.Surface([PLAYER_SIZE_X, PLAYER_SIZE_Y])
      self.image.fill(RED)
      self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
      self.PLAYER_VELOCITY_X = 0
      self.PLAYER_VELOCITY_Y = 0
      self.PLAYER_ACCELERATION_X = 0
      self.PLAYER_ACCELERATION_Y = 0

  def calc_x_movement(self):
      self.PLAYER_ACCELERATION_X += self.PLAYER_VELOCITY_X * PLAYER_FRICTION
      self.PLAYER_VELOCITY_X += self.PLAYER_ACCELERATION_X
      self.rect.x += self.PLAYER_VELOCITY_X + 0.5 * self.PLAYER_ACCELERATION_X

  def calc_gravity(self):
      self.PLAYER_ACCELERATION_Y += PLAYER_GRAVITY
      self.PLAYER_VELOCITY_Y += self.PLAYER_ACCELERATION_Y
      self.rect.y += self.PLAYER_VELOCITY_Y + 0.5 * self.PLAYER_ACCELERATION_Y

  def check_for_V_collisions(self):
      block_hit_list = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
      for block in block_hit_list:
          if self.PLAYER_VELOCITY_Y > 0:
              self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
              self.PLAYER_Y = self.rect.bottom
              self.PLAYER_VELOCITY_Y = 0

  def controls(self):
      keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
      if keys[player_move_left_key]:
          self.PLAYER_ACCELERATION_X = -PLAYER_SPEED

      if keys[player_move_right_key]:
          self.PLAYER_ACCELERATION_X = PLAYER_SPEED

      for event in pg.event.get():
          if event.type == pg.QUIT:
              quitGame()

          if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
              if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                  pg.quit()
                  sys.exit()

              if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                  quitGame()

  def movement(self):
      self.PLAYER_ACCELERATION_X = 0
      self.PLAYER_ACCELERATION_Y = 0
      self.PLAYER_GRAVITY = PLAYER_GRAVITY
      self.controls()
      self.calc_x_movement()
      self.calc_gravity()
      self.check_for_V_collisions()

class Platform(pg.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self, width, height):
      super().__init__()
      self.image = pg.Surface([width, height])
      self.image.fill(YELLOW)
      self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class Level():
  def __init__(self, player):
      self.platform_list = pg.sprite.Group()
      self.enemy_list = pg.sprite.Group()
      self.player = player
      self.level = []

  def update(self):
      self.platform_list.update()
  def draw(self, screen):

      screen.fill(BACK_GROUND_COLOUR)
      self.platform_list.draw(screen)

class Level_01(Level):
  def __init__(self, player):
      Level.__init__(self, player)
      level = [[1000, 10, 0, 300]]
      for platform in level:
          block = Platform(platform[0], platform[1])
          block.rect.x = platform[2]
          block.rect.y = platform[3]
          block.player = self.player
          self.platform_list.add(block)

showStats = True

class Game:
  def __init__(self):
      pg.init()
      pg.font.init()
      pg.mixer.init()
      pg.display.set_caption(GAME_TITLE)
      self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
      self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
      self.fontTypeA = pg.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 10)
      self.GAME_TIMER = 0
      self.running = True

  def new(self):
      self.player = Player()

      level_list = []
      level_list.append(Level_01(self.player))
      self.current_level_no = 0
      self.current_level = level_list[self.current_level_no]
      self.active_sprite_list = pg.sprite.Group()
      self.player.level = self.current_level
      self.player.rect.x = 200
      self.player.rect.y = 0
      self.active_sprite_list.add(self.player)
      self.run()

  def run(self):
      self.playing = True
      while self.playing:
          self.update()
          self.draw()

  def update(self):
      self.active_sprite_list.update()
      self.current_level.update()
      self.player.movement()
      self.GAME_TIMER += (1 / FPS)
      self.clock.tick(FPS)

  def draw(self):
      self.current_level.draw(GAME_WINDOW)
      self.active_sprite_list.draw(GAME_WINDOW)
      if showStats is True:
          self.display_player_stats()
      pg.display.flip()

  def draw_text(self, font_name, text, size, colour, x, y):
      font = pg.font.SysFont(font_name, size)
      text_surface = font.render(text, True, colour)
      text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
      text_rect.midtop = (x, y)
      GAME_WINDOW.blit(text_surface, text_rect)

  def display_player_stats(self):
      text1 = "Vel.Y = " + ("%.2f" % self.player.PLAYER_VELOCITY_Y)
      text2 = "Acc.Y = " + ("%.2f" % self.player.PLAYER_ACCELERATION_Y)
      text3 = "Pos.Y = " + ("%.2f" % self.player.rect.y)
      text4 = "Vel.X = " + ("%.2f" % self.player.PLAYER_VELOCITY_X)
      text5 = "Acc.X = " + ("%.2f" % self.player.PLAYER_ACCELERATION_X)
      text6 = "Pos.X = " + ("%.2f" % self.player.rect.x)
      text7 = "Timer = " + ("%.2f" % self.GAME_TIMER)
      self.draw_text("Comic Sans MS", text1, 10, GREEN, 40, 5)
      self.draw_text("Comic Sans MS", text2, 10, GREEN, 40, 15)
      self.draw_text("Comic Sans MS", text3, 10, GREEN, 40, 25)
      self.draw_text("Comic Sans MS", text4, 10, YELLOW, 40, 40)
      self.draw_text("Comic Sans MS", text5, 10, YELLOW, 40, 50)
      self.draw_text("Comic Sans MS", text6, 10, YELLOW, 40, 60)
      self.draw_text("Comic Sans MS", text7, 10, WHITE, SCREEN_WIDTH - 50, 5)

g = Game() while g.running:
g.new()

pg.quit()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  I've edited your post to make the code block look more readable.  There was a `>` character at the front of every line, so please review the code formatting before posting the question.  That said, what have you tried so far?  This is a lot of code for anyone on this site to have to read to try to figure out your problem so if you can narrow it down to a specific place in the code where you think the problem might be happening you will get better responses.

Comment: BTW: to make code more readable put all constants and classes before `pygame.init()`. Don't create `showStats = True` between classes. And we use `UPPER_CASE` names only for constant values - ie. `self.PLAYER_VELOCITY_X` is not constant.

Comment: use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed - it helps to find problem. Or learn how to use debugger ;)

Comment: You have `self.screen` so you don't need `GAME_WINDOW`

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for the armature post as well! Thanks for the tips and pointers too. Ok so the problem lies somewhere in def calc_x_movement(self): function. I'm sure it might be something to do with the PLAYER_SPEED value.

Comment: I tried the following code within this function had almost solved the problem but there is still something wrong...       if -PLAYER_SPEED < self.PLAYER_VELOCITY_X < PLAYER_SPEED: self.PLAYER_VELOCITY_X = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem are `float` values.

You make calculations on `float` values but `rect.x` keeps only `integer` value so it rounds all `float` calculations to `integer` - but it does it in wrong way and it gives wrong results.

You can keep all calculations as `float` - ie. in variable `self.x`

```
self.x += self.PLAYER_VELOCITY_X + 0.5 * self.PLAYER_ACCELERATION_X
```

and after all calculations set `self.rect.x`

```
self.rect.x = self.x
```

---

**EDIT:**

Probably `rect.x` rounds added values to `floor` so it converts `-0.1` to `-1` instead of `0` and then `rect.x += -0.1` gives `rect.x += -1` instead of `rect.x += 0`

You can also use `round()` to manually convert `float` before you add it

```
self.rect.x += round(self.PLAYER_VELOCITY_X + 0.5 * self.PLAYER_ACCELERATION_X)
```

But using `self.x` to keep `float` values can gives better results.

(`float` can't keep all real values but it shouldn't be a problem. Or you can use [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/decimal.html) modules)